# Creating a countdown timer which survives activity/fragments

Tags: android, android-service

I need to implement a kind of "Timeout' Mechanism.

The requirement is given a time (in milliseconds), start a countdown timer which counts down from the given time.

When time reaches zero, an action (like show a dialog) must be triggered.

This timer must not be bounded by an activity or fragment but should reset to the given time when the user touches the screen.

I am thinking of two ways to implement this:

1) Create a countdown timer inside the application class so it is not bounded by any activity or fragment. `Application` class expose the result via `LiveData`.

2) Create a Bound Service class which houses the countdown timer and expose the result via `BroadcastReciever`.

I just wanna know which is the best approach? or is there even a better approach? I've heard of `JobScheduler` is that work taking a look at for this use case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a normal Thread object and inside its "run()" method do a "while(System.currentMilliseconds() < mFixedTime){}" to loop inside it until a specific fixed Time is reached and passed, but if your Activity is closed you will not be able to intercept display touches events in any way.

Comment: where do you house that code? do you put it inside the application class or inside a service? which is better?

Comment: It seems you just need a simple Timer, so you can create those few lines of code wherever you want. I suggest you to create that new Class (which extends "Thread") inside the Service Class and then do a "new NewThreadClass().start()"